# How do you detect variance and bias problems?

Tags: bias-variance-tradeoff

In practice, given a dataset how do I assess that I have variance or bias problem such that I can move my efforts towards reducing them by using proper models for each case (for example: RandomForests for decreasing variance and GradientBoosting for reducing bias)?

Comment: Bias-variance tradeoff concerns models, not the data.